# Detecting requests from PWA in standalone mode

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I'm attempting to implement PWA server-side detection by altering all links on a page to add a query parameter if in standalone mode. Like this:

```
  if (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches) {
    // @todo: this code breaks ios app.
    $('a').each(function() {
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
      href += (href.match(/\?/) ? '&' : '?') + 'mode=pwa';
      $(this).attr('href', href);
    });
  }
```

This seems to work fine on Android devices, but for some reason, breaks JS on iOS devices. Does anyone know why this code doesn't work on iOS?  Or is there a better way?

Thanks, Joe

Comment: What do you mean by breaks? What's happening? What's not working?

Comment: By "breaks", I mean that when using the app in standalone mode on iOS none of the js works.  It's as if there is an error preventing the js from loading. But, like I said, the js works in safari mobile.

Comment: Just an FYI, I'm dropping this method in favor of using cookies.  But it would still be nice to know what's going on here.

Comment: Agreed, it's annoying pwa stuff is so poorly documented atm. What did your cookie implementation look like @joekrukosky ?

Answer (score 2):

To do this with cookies:

```
// JS side.
      if (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches) {
        document.cookie = 'deviceMode=pwa';
      }
      else {
        document.cookie = 'deviceMode=mobile';
      }   



// PHP Side.
  if ($_COOKIE['deviceMode'] == 'pwa') {
    // Do something.
  }
  elseif ($_COOKIE['deviceMode'] == 'mobile') {
    // Do something else.
  }
  else {
    // And something else.
  }
```